# scss for 3 column responsive footer

Tags: compass-sass

I'm trying to create a 3 column responsive footer where in case of small window size I want each div "foo_col" to shown downt to first div.ie
     foo_col_1
     foo_col_2
     foo_col_3

---HTML code-----

```
<footer>
        <section class="layout">
            <div class="foo_row">
                <div class="foo_col">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i>About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-h"></i>Sign In</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-heart"></i>Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- foo_col_1 -->

                <div class="foo_col">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">All Location</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- foo_col_2 -->

                <div class="foo_col">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-keyboard"></i>Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- foo_col_2 -->

            </div><!-- foo_row -->

        </section><!-- section -->
    </footer><!-- footer -->
```

Need to enhance sass code to take care of small sized window. Currently on resizing the window footer links are not aligning properly.

------footer sass-----

```
footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: lighten($darkgray, 25); 

    @include at-breakpoint($medium){
        text-align:center;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul.nav{

        li{
            a{
                color :$darkblue;
                font-size: .8em;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }
        }
    }
}//footer
```

Comment: So what is your question?  Is your code working, or are you seeing problems with it?

Comment: No footer links are not aligning properly.

Comment: So here is how to turn this question into something people will look at long enough to answer (we are all busy).  Edit the question and 1) put the problem you are having at the top of the question.  2) Change your sass to css (yes, I know, yuck) and make your html and css runnable in the browser, so we can just click on the Play button and see it failing, and 3) Change your title to include the problem (Footer links are not aligning properly is a fine title).  Reply when you are done and I may be able to figure it out myself if nobody else does.